# Analog of a tubular neighborhood for an embedded wedge sum

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-geometry

If you have some embedding of a <del>path connected topological space</del> wedge of spheres $N$ into a compact simply connected smooth $n$ manifold $M$ (like a sphere for example), then

1. is there some kind of analog to a tubular neighborhood for this sort of embedding? i.e. some $T$ that is a codimension 0 smooth submanifold of $M$ which deformation retracts to $N$, and
2. what can *easily* be said about the (co)homology of such a space in relation to $N$ (and its ring structure)?

My main question is for wedges of spheres in a higher dimension sphere, <del>so if the above seems too general then lets restrict to this. I think 1. is a silly question and I just don't have the right definition laying around.</del>

For example, consider $S^1\vee S^1$ embedded in an $\mathbb{R}^3 \subset S^3$. Then a connected sum of two solid tori, call this $T$, satisfies my conditions. The cohomology of $S^1\vee S^1 $ has two basis elements in degree 1 with trivial product. <del>The cohomology of $T$ has two generators in degree 1, two in degree 2, and one in degree 3 (there are two non-trivial products of a thing in degree one with a thing in degree 2).</del>  I forgot here that a solid torus has a boundary.

<del>In a way, the cohomology of $T$ comes from adding dual elements in the right degrees.  In general, for a wedge sum of spheres I think the example above sort of demonstrates whats going on. Does this seem right?</del>

Comment: Question 1 seems a little far fetched indeed, at least in full generality.

Comment: lets just stick with wedges of spheres then.

Comment: This seems a little bit similar to an argument in Section 2 of a recent article I wrote with Tom Baird: http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3341.  There we construct a sort of "tubular neighborhood" for a normal crossings divisor in a non-singular algebraic set.  But really the point is just that the normal crossings divisor is locally like a (nice) wedge of codimension 1 submanifolds.  Anyway, the arguments could be of some use to you (maybe).